# Model-View-Controller Pattern in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller

What's first thing to do in MVC pattern? In CodeIgniter, we're supposed to build Model first, then Controllers but I've read somewhere build first View.

So, building MVC app: **What I need to build first, What modules I need (Using Express.js framework)**?

Thanks <3

Comment: You need a framework and asking for a framework is not warmly welcomed here. There are several MVC frameworks for node.js. The other part of the question, what should be built first, is totally opinion based which also doesn't fit SO.

Comment: What do you recommend? Just wanna hear your opinion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a beginner it is common to have issues like these. Well like most of the frameworks node.js also has `models,views and controllers`.

You can build your models using `mongoose(No sql)` https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose
or `sequalize(for mysql/postgesql etc)` http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/

for views node.js supports templating engines like `jade` and `ejs`

and as you already know you may put your business logic in controllers

Here is a detailed example to get you started http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/05/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-crud/

hope it helps :)